# SonarQube exception

Tags: ruby, sonarqube

When I run SonarQube using "StartSonar.bat", the command line window shows -

```
`jvm 1    | 2014.10.16 17:32:14 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up`
```

but when I hit url - `http://localhost:9000/` from my machine, I get following error. I am pretty much new in this. Please suggest how could I resolve this. 
I am using SonarQube version 4.5 and Operating System - Windows 7 Professional.

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: uninitialized constant I18n
    from org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2689:in `const_missing'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record.rb:83:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1075:in `require'
    from jar:file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from jar:file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268:in `require_frameworks'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268:in `require_frameworks'
    from file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:51:in `require_frameworks_with_servlet_env'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:134:in `process'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
    from C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:55:in `(root)'
    from file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'

    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant I18n
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2689)
    at RUBY.(root)(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record.rb:83)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1075)
    at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)
    at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)
    at RUBY.(root)(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks_with_servlet_env(file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:51)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223)
    at RUBY.process(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:134)
    at RUBY.run(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094)
    at RUBY.(root)(C:/sonarqube-4.5/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:55)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/C:/sonarqube-4.5/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25)
```

Comment: You can have a look at this tutorial to see how it's setup http://sharpten.com/blog/2014/05/02/sonarqube_for_php_project.html

Comment: Is it a fresh install of SQ 4.5? Have you followed the install guide step by step?

Comment: Yes, It is fresh installation and followed the installation guide.

Comment: Have you installed any plugins over the default instance of SonarQube. My suggestion would be to uninstall all plugins except the default ones and restart sonar and check if its working or not.

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same issue, first caused by lack of java_home in env. variables but after adding it i saw above error. Solution for me was stop & uninstall service, delete whole dir and install it once again, according to install manual.